# How to display raw sql query output in html table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have the following table generate by raw SQL query in Laravel:

```
+----------+-------+-------+
| Products | Price | Shop  |
+----------+-------+-------+
| Jacket   | 300.0 | Shop1 |
| T-Shirt  | 300.0 | Shop1 |
| Jacket   | 500.0 | Shop2 |
| Shoes    | 200.0 | Shop2 |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

Have no idea how to loop through this data, so I get result like this in browser:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Product | Shop1 | Shop2 |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Jacket  | 300.0 | 500.0 |
| T-Shirt | 300.0 | NULL  |
| Shoes   | NULL  | 200.0 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the net that explain how to get data from a database and output it, and there are plenty of laravel tutorials that show how to output queries. Have at it, and good luck.

Comment: This is related to `database` more than `laravel`. The OP is trying to retrieve price for the product that is available in `shop1` and `shop2`. The product may be in both shop1 & shop2, only in shop1, only in shop2. However the `Jacket` should have been twice in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
    SELECT a.product, 
       (SELECT max(b.price) 
        FROM   yourtable b 
        WHERE  b.product = a.product 
               AND b.shop = 'Shop1') shop1, 
       (SELECT max(c.price) 
        FROM   yourtable c 
        WHERE  c.product = a.product 
               AND b.shop = 'Shop2') shop2 
FROM   yourtable a group by a.product
```