# How to add @foreach to SQL raw statement in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

I have an array `$shop_ids`, so I would like to loop through and add these ids to subqueries of the SQL statement. Number of SQL subqueries should be equal to the number of ids.

I would expect a query like this, but obviously `@foreach` doesn't work and just becomes part of SQL query:

```
DB::select('select
        pr.product_name,
        pr.brand,
        coalesce(pr.weight, pr.volume) wv,
        sli.quantity
        {{@foreach ($shop_ids as $id)
                ,{{(select
        p.price

        from prices p
            inner join (
                select p1.product_id id, max(p1.created_at) maxed_date

                from prices p1

                group by p1.product_id, p1.shop_id) grouped on grouped.maxed_date=p.created_at

        join shop_names s on s.id=p.shop_id
        where p.product_id=sli.product_id
        and s.id=$id)}}}}

        from shopping_list_items sli
        join products pr on pr.id=sli.product_id

        where sli.shopping_list_id= :slid

        order by 5 asc', ['slid'=>$this->id])
```

Comment: Create a string in loop then concatenate accordingly.

Comment: Could you please provide an example. Don't understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want such a lot sub-queries inside and what result do want to get?

Comment: @jaro1989 this is the result I expect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397260/how-to-display-raw-sql-query-output-in-html-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way as an example -

```
$ids_query = '';
// generate the queries in loop
foreach ($shop_ids as $id) {
    $ids_query .= ", (select ..... where .. and s.id=$id)";
}
// use in the main query
DB::select("select
        ...,
        sli.quantity
        $ids_query
        from shopping_list_items sli
        ...
        order by 5 asc", ['slid'=>$this->id]);
```